# Login with Active Directory not working

Tags: opensuse, authentication, active-directory

I've just installed the openSUSE tumbleweed Snapshot 20170625 and want to configure Windows Domain login on console. I've successfully added the machine to the domain but when I try to login with `domain\user` I get `login incorrect` and in the journal it says `User not known to the underlying authentication module`

I've done this successfully on the 13.1 release... what have I forgot?

Comment: I finally deleted the installation and made a new one with the leap version. worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In the smb.conf what is your winbind separator ? 
By default it is +, so for login it's : domain+user.

So if you want you can switch it to \ but i'm not sure it's not in use elsewhere.

Comment: The only winbind param I have in smb.conf is `winbind refresh tickets` I have also tried to login with `domain+user` but it failed too. Setting it manually didn't help either...

Comment: I've checked the eventlog on the Domain Controller it seems the DC doesn't get asked...